# Jquery, smooth transition slide after floated elements disappear

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm still somewhat new to jquery, which you'll likely notice.

[Check out my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLcCT/)

Here's the jquery code, though I think you'll need to see the example for this to be clear:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $('body').click(function(event) {
                    if($(event.target).is('.pageOne')) {
                        $('.pageTwo, .pageThree, .pageFour').fadeOut();
                                                    }

                    else if ($(event.target).is('.pageTwo')) {
                        $('.pageOne, .pageThree, .pageFour').fadeOut();
                        }

                    else if ($(event.target).is('.pageThree')) {
                        $('.pageFour, .pageTwo, .pageOne').fadeOut(); }

                    else if ($(event.target).is('.pageFour')) {
                        $('.pageThree, .pageTwo, .pageOne').fadeOut(); }
                });



            }); // end ready
```

This is just a prototype which I might later translate into something useful. 
Basically what I'm trying to do is, when you click on one of the coloured articles, the rest disappear (which works), but then you'll notice that the item that was clicked kind of jumps to the left, since it is floated to the left.

What I want is for that clicked article to smoothly slide towards the left somehow.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can replace `fadeOut()` with the `animate()` method like this:

```
$('.pageTwo, .pageThree, .pageFour').animate({'width':'0','opacity':'0'});
```

Check the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/QLcCT/6/**